# Connecting Pir sensor in L and H position. How.?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I was going through this article
[Testing a Pir](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/testing-a-pir) and i see a section called "Retriggering". There are two positioning.

1. L Position
2. H Position

**L position**, the LED does not stay on when moving in front of it but actually turns on and off every second or so. But in **H position** LED does stay on the entire time that something is moving.

This is output of the program

```
pi@nikhilbhagath:~/pi/occupied-device $ python pir.py
('Motion detected! ', True)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected! ', True)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected! ', True)
('Motion detected! ', True)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected! ', True)
('Motion detected! ', True)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
('Motion detected!', False)
^Z
[35]+  Stopped                 python pir.py
pi@nikhilbhagath:~/pi/occupied-device $
```

But I want my LED to stay on for a longer time. How can I do it. ? ?

Thank you.

Comment: L position is for toggle LED, not much use in practical , In H position the LED will stay high when motion else Low.

Comment: http://hackaholic.info/pir-motion-detection-sensor/

Comment: Can u tell me how is the H positioning made in the PIR . ?